# What is the right function to use to list NFT collection with a fixed price?

Tags: solidity, remix, nft, price, opensea

New solidity learner here. I have created a solidity code to mint NFTs. But I am struggling to create a function that would help me set a fixed price in ether for all listed tokens. Any help or guidance is much appreciated. Attaching the sample code below that I used to deploy NFTS in testnet.opensea.io via IPFS.

```html
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract NFT_TOKEN is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
    using Strings for uint256;
    
    string public baseURI;
    string public baseExtension = ".json";
    uint256 public cost = 0.01 ether;
    uint256 public maxSupply = 10000;
    uint256 public maxMintAmount = 20;
    bool public paused = false;
    
    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        string memory _initBaseURI
    )   ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
        setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);
        mint(msg.sender, 1);
            
    }
      
    // internal
    function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return baseURI;
    }
    
    // public
    function mint(address _to, uint256 _mintAmount) public payable {
        uint256 supply = totalSupply();
        require(!paused);
        require(_mintAmount > 0);
        require(_mintAmount <= maxMintAmount);
        require(supply + _mintAmount <= maxSupply);
        
        if(msg.sender != owner()) {
            require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount);
        }
        
        for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++) {
            _safeMint(_to, supply + i);
        }
          
    }
      
    function walletOfOwner(address _owner)
        public
        view
        returns (uint256[] memory)
            
      {
        uint256 ownerTokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);
        uint256[] memory tokenIds = new uint256[](ownerTokenCount);
        for (uint256 i; i < ownerTokenCount; i++) {
            tokenIds[i] = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(_owner, i);
        }
        return tokenIds;
    }
    
    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        virtual
        override
        returns (string memory)
      {
        require(
            _exists(tokenId),
            "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token"
        );
        
        string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();
        return 
          bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0
            ? string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, tokenId.toString(), baseExtension))
            : "";
    }
      
    // only owner
    function  setCost(uint256 _newCost) public onlyOwner() {
        cost = _newCost;
          
    }
      
    function setmaxMintAmount(uint256 _newmaxMintAmount) public onlyOwner() {
        maxMintAmount = _newmaxMintAmount;
    }
      
    function setBaseURI(string memory _newBaseURI) public onlyOwner() {
        baseURI = _newBaseURI;
    }
      
    function setBaseExtension(string memory _newBaseExtension) public onlyOwner() {
        baseExtension = _newBaseExtension;
    }
      
    function pause(bool _state) public onlyOwner() {
        paused = _state;
    }
      
    function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner() {
        require(payable(msg.sender).send(address(this).balance));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this `mint` function you are already set up to receive payments for your NFTs. To enforce payments when someone calls your mint function, add a requirement for transaction value to equal cost per NFT x number of NFTs being minted.

```
require(msg.value == cost * _mintAmount, "Not the right amount of ETH");
```

Since there is no way to update your `cost` this is a fixed payment.

Comment: Hey there, Sorry. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I was more curious about the listing value of NFTs in the market place. Suppose, Lets say I mint all 10,000 NFTs to open sea to my wallet ID and list each of those NFTs for particular list price, Is it doable via smart contract? or a better way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

As @randomquestion mentioned, you need to put a price in smart contract to collect initial sale revenue, and this sale should happen on your mint page.

opensea is a secondary trading platform, users who minted will set the price of their choice for their nfts if they want to trade.

unless you want to mint all nfts to your wallet and then list each for different price on secondary platform, not recommended as it will take you so much time to list each.

I hope you have the idea now as its 6 months late.